# Xcode 5 quits unexpectedly while opening storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Basically, I checked out from a repository and tried to open main.storyboard but the Xcode 5 quits unexpectedly. On my another iMac which runs Mavericks and Xcode 5.1.1, I can open the storyboard. None of using custom fonts actually. Here's the problem report details: http://pastebin.com/1Juq0qFz.

I did the clean, rebuild and it failed too. Here's the error:

```
Interface Builder Storyboard
    CompileStoryboard beeMessengeriOS/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
        cd /Users/ngfajar/Documents/BeeMessengerIOS
        export IBSC_MINIMUM_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION=6.1
        export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
        export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --minimum-deployment-target 6.1 --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/ngfajar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/beeMessengeriOS-dimmqnsrturiuiacmvcnorauhifs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/beeMessengeriOS.app/Base.lproj/Main.storyboardc /Users/ngfajar/Documents/BeeMessengerIOS/beeMessengeriOS/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard

    Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

My VMWare runs Mountain Lion 10.8.4 with Xcode 5.1.1. Any solution to this problem?

**EDIT**

I found out that Main.Storyboard turned into red in Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources

Comment: Easiest way if you don't make any changes to the storyboard, just delete the storyboard and re-pull from the repo. You can also, go to the project directory -> right click on the .xcodeproj -> show package content -> right click on project.xcworkspace -> open folder xcshareddata -> delete the file with extension .xccheckout

Comment: @Bejibun i dont find 'open folder xcshareddata' after clicking right on project.xcworkspace

Comment: just search for the .xccheckout file and delete it and try to pull from repo. the best thing just delete the storyboard and repull

Comment: @Bejibun delete as move to trash or remove references?

Comment: just make a backup and put on any folder, then remove the one in the project to the trash

Comment: @Bejibun deleted the storyboard, committed, and repulled. main.storyboard doesn't appear in project

Comment: try to search in the project folder, and re-drag it into the project

Comment: @Bejibun there's no main.storyboard in base.lproj after repulling

Comment: just store back the one from ur backup, see if that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below steps made it fix:

1. Open storyboard as source code
2. Remove this appearanceType="aqua"
3. Save, re-open Xcode and voila!

Comment: but there is no appearanceType in my code. what should I do ?